# Optimal bulk query size for multiSearch in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, algorithm, elasticsearch

I am trying to query elasticsearch with multisearch , but it doesn't seems to improve the time a lot.

For approx **70k queries** , time taken by different bulk_sizes are :

For **single search** for every item time taken = **2611s**

For **multisearch (bulksize=1000)** time taken = **2400s**

For **multisearch (bulksize=10)** time taken = **2326s**

So, I need to know

a) Is this the correct way to do MultiSearch ?

b) What is the optimal Bulk Size for Multi Search ?

Here'e my code :

```
search_arr = []

        for k in range(i,i+BULK_SIZE):
            search_arr.append({'index':'test'})
            search_arr.append({"query": {"match": {"title": title[k]}}, "size": 5})
        request =''
        for each in search_arr:
            request += '%s \n' %json.dumps(each)

        resp = es.msearch(body=request)
```

Answer (score 3):

The number of concurrent searches is limited by the Search Thread Pool.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html

> For count/search operations. 
>   Thread pool type is fixed with a size of int((# of available_processors * 3) / 2) + 1, queue_size of 1000.

This means if you have single processor, then you will have 2 concurrent searches, and rest of the requests will go into the queue and will be processed as and when the threads become available again.